# Upload file with selenide webdriver without any input

Tags: java, testing, automation, automated-tests, selenide

I am trying to upload file using java selenide automation test.

Place I wrote my test uses upload box without any input value near it.

Upload box is id='file'

I tried to used:

```
$(By.cssSelector("[id='file']")).uploadFile(new File("myfilePackage" + File.separator + "picture.jpg"))
```

but that did't help cause there is no input box for file upload.

Then I tried to use:

```
WebElement elem = getWebDriver().findElement(By.cssSelector("[id='file']"));
String js = "arguments[0].style.height='auto'; arguments[0].style.visibility='visible';";

((JavascriptExecutor) getWebDriver()).executeScript(js, elem);
elem.sendKeys("wholePath\\picture.png");
```

to make the element visible but I get unkown error: canno focus element\n ...

I got it using but this is not what I want:

```
WebElement elem = getWebDriver().findElement(By.cssSelector("[id='file']"));

((RemoteWebElement) elem ).setFileDetector(new LocalFileDetector());

elem.sendKeys("C:FullPath\\picture.png");
```

Is there any other way to get file from this kind of upload? I want to upload it from Intellij Package

Comment: just offtop comment: `$(By.cssSelector("[id='file']")) = $(By.cssSelector("#file")) = $("#file") in Selenide`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution was very funny - Selenide can't resolve upload in "Evaluate Code Fragment" mode. Basically, my question also answers.

Answer (score 0):

WebDriver allows using `sendKeys` for file uploading only in case of `input` with `type=file`. As Selenide is just a WebDriver wrapper, it uses the same technique: https://github.com/codeborne/selenide/blob/8d545daa1286936e2041c1e8dd01801734c7fa39/src/main/java/com/codeborne/selenide/commands/UploadFile.java#L52

You may try asking your devs, if there's a hidden input present. Or in case of a custom uploader there're couple of other options you can try:

- OCR tools like SikuliX;
- creating a backdoor with a hidden input (ask developers for that), which duplicates original uploader's behavior.

I'd pick the second option, as for FE-devs it should be an easy one. They may just automatically remove corresponding backdoors in production builds.